# Some questions are highlighted for a not-logged-in user, is that by design?

Tags: bug

I'm not (yet) an SF user, so I got here out of curiosity after we migrated a question from SO to SF. I was surprised to see that, on the main page, some questions were highlighted as if I had any "interesting tags" defined, but I didn't even have an account.

This is in mobile version, not sure if it's relevant.

P.S. I can't reproduce it now, after I created an account, even when logging out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a long outstanding bug that they can't reproduce consistantly: [Mobile site highlighting someone elses favourite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128047/mobile-site-highlighting-someone-elses-favourite-tags)

Comment: Ah, so this can be dupe-closed, I guess. I didn't find the original question, probably because I didn't include the words "mobile site". Thanks.

Comment: And with the hurricane they probably a) have bigger fish to fry right now and b) would want to move everything back to the main site before fixing it. We've been very fortunate that the service is running well.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - it's also on a different site (meta.so instead of meta.se). So I'll leave it here as a signpost for others :)

Comment: Missed that. Silly me :)